# 6-month migration path from asp to asp.net - is it worth interopping?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I'm going to migrate from asp to asp.net over the next few months. Is it worth building .NET interop components and calling them through COM wrappers in ASP to move things along? If so - what types of components would you make? Data access? It's largely a CRUD and reporting application.

Comment: If you're going to the 4.0 framework, it would probably take less time to use EF for your CRUD.  That is just an opinion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't go down the COM path. Considering both apps are web based and the type of operations or transaction are fairly standard, I suggest you look at web services rather than com object and building throwing away wrappers. These web services can immediately be consumed as building block in your new ASP.NET application project too.

Comment: I still haven't found a decent way to secure those in my environment. Advice? I use Session state under http in Classic ASP.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? If you are after securing the ws calls try looking into the use of API key. You can then use it in both asp and aspnet with ease

Answer (score 1):

It's worth doing but go directly to ASP.NET MVC, it is most similar to Classic ASP style than regular .NET

Comment: MVC is a lot better than WebForms and interoping isn't great. That's purely a (embittered!) support viewpoint though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar but not a full migration. I decided to go the COM route so that I could take advantage of .NET while still having reusable components down the road in case a full rewrite were to become necessary. The COM route is pretty straight forward and is very trivial to glue into ASP code. I would recommend it if you want to build a piece at a time.

In my case I made some Active Directory components and some other general purpose ones.